# Returning a record from a definition in Coq

Tags: coq

Suppose I've got a `record` that contains two `nats`.

```
Record toy := {
    num1 : nat;
    num2 : nat
}.
```

I want to build a definition that given two `nats` returns a `record` containing those two `nats`.

```
Definition args_to_toy_record (n1 : nat) (n2 : nat) : toy := 
 (* {num1 = n1;  num2 = n2} ?? *)
```

Unfortunately, the official documentation only seems to cover the simpler cases when the return type is a `bool` or a `nat`. Is such a thing possible in `coq`? If yes, what is the best method to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had it almost right.  You just need slightly different syntax:

```
Record toy := {
    num1 : nat;
    num2 : nat
}.

Definition args_to_toy_record (n1 : nat) (n2 : nat) : toy :=
 {| num1 := n1;  num2 := n2 |}.
```

Alternatively, you can use regular constructor syntax. Every record `toto` in Coq is declared as an inductive (sometimes, coinductive) type with a single constructor `Build_toto`, whose arguments are exactly the fields of the record:

```
Definition args_to_toy_record (n1 : nat) (n2 : nat) : toy :=
  Build_toy n1 n2.
```

You can also name the record constructor explicitly, like this:

```
Record toy := Toy {
    num1 : nat;
    num2 : nat
}.

Definition args_to_toy_record (n1 : nat) (n2 : nat) : toy :=
  Toy n1 n2.
```